# How to display text value 'X' if number is 0.00. SQL Server, Stored Procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I want that value would be displayed in text 'X' when amount is equal 0.00

Now code looks like this:

`SELECT SUM(Amount * 0.01) AS Amount`

And I tried:

```
select CASE
    WHEN SUM(Amount * 0.01) = 0.00 THEN 'X'
    ELSE SUM(Amount * 0.01)
    END AS Amount
```

Now output looks like this:

```
Amount
0.00    
21.04   
8.34
```

I expect the output:

```
Amount
X
21.04
8.34
```

## ========================================

Added/edited info

If i use like this (now SUM(Amount1 * 0.01) = 1)

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT UserId
,CASE
    WHEN SUM(Amount1 * 0.01) = 1 THEN 'X'
    ELSE cast(SUM(Amount1 * 0.01) as varchar )
END AS Amount1
, CASE
    WHEN SUM(Amount2 * 0.01) = 1 THEN 'X'
    ELSE cast(SUM(Amount2 * 0.01) as varchar )
END AS Amount2
FROM Table1
GROUP BY UserId
) as t1
```

Result:

```
Amount1 Amount2
X       15.01
21.04   X
8.30    9.70
```

and now i wanna display another table with sum amount

```
SELECT UserId, Amount1 + Amount2 as AllSum from t1
```

Expected result:

```
AllSum
15.01
21.04
18.00
```

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't do this in your SQL at all. `'X'` isn't a number, meaning that you would have to convert your numerical values to a `varchar`. In the results above, that would end up meaning that `'8.34'` **>** `'21.04'`. This is something for your presentation layer, not your SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is good, but you have to cast so all paths of the CASE lead to the same datatype:

```
SELECT  id
,       CASE WHEN SUM(x.Amount * 0.01) = 0.00 THEN 'X'
            ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), SUM(x.Amount * 0.01))
        END AS Amount
FROM    (
            VALUES ( 1, 0.0 )
            ,       (1, 0.0)
            ,       (2, 1.0)
            ,       (2, 3.0)
        ) x ( id, Amount )
GROUP BY x.id
```

Comment: It's not about the same datatype or not, it's about the datatype precedence, because a `CASE` expression will returns the highest precedence type from the set of types.

Comment: @Sami, that's true, but I'd rather not depend on datatype precedence. I think it's better to explicitly convert all paths to the same datatype, then you'll always know what the resulting datatype will be.

Comment: Nope, you just gives the OP a wrong information _"but you have to cast so all paths of the CASE lead to the same datatype"_ and it's unnecessary to cast to the same datatype, such [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e1b093e7cf70eaf16d326ba5876588ca).

Answer (score 1):

You can use your `case..when` expression by a type conversion to be able not to get type-mismatch :

```
CASE
    WHEN SUM(Amount * 0.01) = 0 THEN 'X'
    ELSE cast(SUM(Amount * 0.01) as varchar(10) )
END AS Amount
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to **[`CAST() / CONVERT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** the result to a `VARCHAR(n)` to get the results needed.
SQL Server will try to convert the string `'X'` to a `NUMERIC` value and fail, because numeric datatypes has highest **[`precedence`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** than string datatypes, thus why you'll get the following error:

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

The **[`CASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** expression returns the highest precedence type from the set of types, which is in your case `NUMERIC`.

So, to solve this, you should convert the results to `VARCHAR(10)` as:

```
SELECT Id,
       CASE WHEN SUM(Amount * 0.01) = 0 THEN 'X'
            ELSE CAST(SUM(Amount * 0.01) AS VARCHAR(10))
       END Amount
FROM
(
  VALUES (1, 0.0),
         (1, 0.0),
         (2, 1.0),
         (2, 3.0)
) T(Id, Amount)
GROUP BY Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE
WHEN cast(SUM(Amount * 0.01)as int) = 0 THEN cast('X' as varchar(100))
ELSE cast(SUM(Amount * 0.01)as varchar(100))
END AS Amount
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
select CASE SUM(Amount * 0.01)
    WHEN 0.00 THEN 'X'
    ELSE CAST(SUM(Amount * 0.01) AS VARCHAR(10)) 
    END AS Amount
```

By the way, which version of SQL server are you using? When I run your query, I get an error

> "Error converting data type varchar to numeric."

Comment: My query could be wrong. I wrote it on the spot. This is like map what the result i wanna get.
My full query is much more complex. 

sql server 2017